# Converting complicated list to dataframe in R

Tags: r

Example of the data:

```
x<- list(list(Country = "A1", Risks = list(list(Name = "test", 
    Value = "2.0", 
    Outlook = "Unchanged", UpdatedOn = "2020-12-30", History = list(
        list(Value = "1.9", UpdatedOn = "2015-05-11"), list(Value = "2.1", 
            UpdatedOn = "2016-07-05"), list(Value = "2.2", UpdatedOn = "2017-05-15"), 
        list(Value = "29.3", UpdatedOn = "2017-09-05"), list(Value = "2.4", 
            UpdatedOn = "2018-06-18"), list(Value = "2.2", UpdatedOn = "2018-08-06"), 
        list(Value = "29.4", UpdatedOn = "2018-11-28"), list(Value = "2.5", 
            UpdatedOn = "2019-03-11"), list(Value = "2.7", UpdatedOn = "2019-08-28"), 
        list(Value = "2.8", UpdatedOn = "2019-11-11"), list(Value = "2.2", 
            UpdatedOn = "2019-12-16"), list(Value = "2.3", UpdatedOn = "2020-03-23"), 
        list(Value = "19.9", UpdatedOn = "2020-03-31"), list(Value = "2.0", 
            UpdatedOn = "2020-05-04"), list(Value = "2.3", UpdatedOn = "2020-06-15"), 
        list(Value = "2.3", UpdatedOn = "2020-12-17"), list(Value = "2.0", 
            UpdatedOn = "2020-12-30"))))), list(Country = "A2", 
    Risks = list(list(Name = "Test", Value = "3.7",  
        Outlook = "Unchanged", UpdatedOn = "2020-11-23", History = list(
            list(Value = "1.8", UpdatedOn = "2016-05-03"), list(
                Value = "29.0", UpdatedOn = "2016-07-18"), list(
                Value = "29.3", UpdatedOn = "2016-10-03"), list(
                Value = "2.4", UpdatedOn = "2016-11-21"), list(
                Value = "2.1", UpdatedOn = "2017-08-07"), list(
                Value = "2.4", UpdatedOn = "2017-09-18"), list(
                Value = "2.2", UpdatedOn = "2018-04-09"), list(
                Value = "2.3", UpdatedOn = "2018-06-25"), list(
                Value = "2.3", UpdatedOn = "2018-11-12"), list(
                Value = "2.5", UpdatedOn = "2019-05-28"), list(
                Value = "29.6", UpdatedOn = "2020-03-23"), list(
                Value = "39.2", UpdatedOn = "2020-06-01"), list(
                Value = "4.0", UpdatedOn = "2020-11-04"), list(
                Value = "3.7", UpdatedOn = "2020-11-23"))))))
```

So I would like to convert the above list (which contains many lists inside) to a simple dataframe which looks like this:

```
  Country Name Value   Outlook  UpdatedOn
1      A1 test   2.0 Unchanged 2020-12-30
2      A2 test   3.7 Unchanged 2020-11-23
```

So the "History" aspect of the list is not required at all.

What I've tried so far is to get to the important parts of the list that I need to do for each country, e.g. for country A1:

```
> x[[1]][[2]][[1]][1:4]
$Name
[1] "test"

$Value
[1] "2.0"

$Outlook
[1] "Unchanged"

$UpdatedOn
[1] "2020-12-30"
```

But I am not sure how to convert this to then the dataframe structure, and more importantly how to do this for every country. I could loop and append and use `x[[2]][[2]][[1]][1:4]` for country A2 for example but any help on the best way would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library( data.table ); library( tidyverse )
data.table::rbindlist( x ) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider( Risks )

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Country Name  Value Outlook   UpdatedOn  History    
  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <list>     
1 A1      test  2.0   Unchanged 2020-12-30 <list [17]>
2 A2      Test  3.7   Unchanged 2020-11-23 <list [14]>
```

Comment: I get: `Error: 'unnest_wider' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'` What version of tidyr is required?

Comment: i am using tidyr_1.1.2. unnest_wider() seems to be available since 1.0.0 (releasaed about 1.5 years ago), so perhaps it's time for a package update ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(x) %>%
    unnest_wider(Risks)
```